# Reduce resource usage of this JS program?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, resources, resource-management

I wrote the following JS program, which i'm running from the command line using node.

```
//step one: create an array of remaining creatures
var remainingCreatures = [];

//some config variables:
var amt = 1000; //amount of creatues generated
var maxhlt = 1000; //max value for creature health stat
var minhlt = 100; //min value for creature health stat
var maxatk = 100; //max value for creature attack stat
var minatk = 1; //min value for creature attack stat

function remove(target) { //helper function to easily remove creatues from the array
  var index = remainingCreatures.indexOf(target);
if (index > -1) {
  remainingCreatures.splice(index, 1);
}

}

//generate creatures
//each creature has an Attack, Health, and Aggressiveness , as well as Instabillity, the average of the three
//A creature's Instabillity is added to the attack points of its opponent in fights.
for (var i = 0; i < amt; i++) {
  var atkVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxatk) + minatk);
  var hltVal = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxhlt) + minhlt);
  var insVal = (atkVal + hltVal) / 2;

  remainingCreatures[i] = {num: i, atk: atkVal, hlt: hltVal, ins: insVal, fts: 0, ihlt: hltVal};
}
console.log(amt + " creatues generated, starting melee...");



function fight(cr1, cr2) { //function to handle fighting, randomly creates creature pairs and has them fight
  function attack(a, b) {
         console.log("[ROUND 1] Creature 1 (#" + a.num + ") is attacking first.");
    b.hlt = b.hlt - (a.atk + b.ins);
    console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + b.num + " health reduced to " + b.hlt);
    if (b.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + b.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(b);
    } else {
      console.log("[ROUND 2] Creature 2 (#" + b.num + ") is attacking second.");
      a.hlt = a.hlt - (b.atk + a.ins);
      console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + a.num + " health reduced to " + a.hlt);
      if (a.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + a.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(a);
    }
    }
  }
  console.log("[FIGHT] Pair generated: Creature #" + cr1.num + " and Creature #" + cr2.num);
  cr1.fts++;
  cr2.fts++;
   if (cr1.ins <= cr2.ins) {
    attack(cr1, cr2);
   } else {
    attack(cr2, cr1);
   }
}


for(;true;) {
  if(remainingCreatures.length == 1) break;
  fight(remainingCreatures[Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length)], remainingCreatures[Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length)]);
}

console.log(" ");
console.log("[WIN] Creature #" + remainingCreatures[0].num + " has won!");
console.log("Starting array size was " + amt + " creatures")
console.log(remainingCreatures[0]);
```

For some reason, this starts to slow down and eventually choke when `amt` is set to really big numbers, like one million. For reference, that's the number of objects that will be generated and added to an array - as you can probably see in the code, this array gets looped through a lot. But even with one million objects, each object is only around 80 bytes, maximum. And the calculations this program is doing are very basic.

So my question is: why is running this program so resource intensive, and how can I fix or mitigate it without changing the function of the program too drastically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a million of anything will take a toll on performance, no matter how small.
The other issue is that your design is inherently inefficient.

Look at your `remove()` function. It first finds the index of the element, then removes it. If you have one million elements in that array, on average, it will need to compare the passed value with *500,000 elements* just to find it before it can remove. There's one easy way to fix this; pass indices directly rather than using `.indexOf`.

```js
function fight(ind1, ind2) { //function to handle fighting, randomly creates creature pairs and has them fight
  var cr1 = remainingCreatures[ind1];
  var cr2 = remainingCreatures[ind2];
  function attack(a, b) {
         console.log("[ROUND 1] Creature 1 (#" + a.num + ") is attacking first.");
    b.hlt = b.hlt - (a.atk + b.ins);
    console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + b.num + " health reduced to " + b.hlt);
    if (b.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + b.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(ind2);
    } else {
      console.log("[ROUND 2] Creature 2 (#" + b.num + ") is attacking second.");
      a.hlt = a.hlt - (b.atk + a.ins);
      console.log("[HIT] Creature #" + a.num + " health reduced to " + a.hlt);
      if (a.hlt <= 0) {
      console.log("[DEATH] Creature #" + a.num + " Eliminated");
      remove(ind1);
    }
    }
  }
  console.log("[FIGHT] Pair generated: Creature #" + cr1.num + " and Creature #" + cr2.num);
  cr1.fts++;
  cr2.fts++;
   if (cr1.ins <= cr2.ins) {
    attack(cr1, cr2);
   } else {
    attack(cr2, cr1);
   }
}


for(;true;) {
  if(remainingCreatures.length == 1) break;
  fight(Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length), Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length));
}
```

There aren't many other ways to easily improve performance, but that alone should be enough. To make your code more readable, though, consider replacing this:

```js
for(;true;) {
  if(remainingCreatures.length == 1) break;
    fight(Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length), Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length));
}
```

with this:

```js
// Consider using === and !== as best practice, but not necessary here
while (remainingCreatures.length != 1)
    fight(Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length), Math.floor(Math.random() * remainingCreatures.length));
```

([See this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) for info on that comment.)

Comment: "*it will need to compare the passed value with 500,000 elements just to find it before it can remove*" and a removal can then trigger a forward shuffling of the array to close the gap. A map/set might be more efficient.

Comment: I should note that `cr1` and `cr2` are being picked *randomly* from the array, which might interfere with 101arrowz's suggestion of passing the indices as I don't actually know them.

Comment: @VLAZ thing is, sets are ES6 and this is clearly not ES6 so that's the only reason I suggested arrays. Otherwise sets are absolutely superior. Also, it's still better to suffer one O(n) operation than two. (But OP should try using ES6, it's so much better)

Comment: @TheDeveloperNextDoor Read the code I gave again. You pass random *indices* to the function, not random values. So it works. Also see what's passed to `remove` now.

Comment: @101arrowz thanks, that's helpful. I would have to change `remove()` to use the `target` variable in its `if` statement instead of the `index` variable for this to work properly, correct?

Comment: No, you don't. The only changes you need are above. I think you're trying too hard to imagine removing a value rather than cutting out an index, but most of the time, removing by index is far more efficient.

Comment: "*and this is clearly not ES6*" it's running in Node. How old a version of would Node have to be to not support ES6?

Comment: It's not the lack of support, it's just that given by OP's use of `var`, `function`, and a variety of C-esque constructs, all of which look very ES3 to me, I would assume using ES6 would be a pretty big leap. I suppose you could use *just* ES6 Set and nothing else though. You can post an answer using Set if you want.